# How do you pull a commit that someone else made on your branch?

Tags: git, github

I have some work done on a branch: `WIP-my-branch`. I pushed up my branch and made a PR (yet to be approved b/c it's in progress). I got stuck, then asked for help; a co-worker then pushed up a commit on to my branch. I can see her commit on Github, but doing `git pull` on my branch does not get her commit (the most recent commit on the branch). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your co-worker's remote and merge in their changes.

```
git remote add coworker_remote url_to_their_repo
git remote update
git merge coworker_remote/WIP-my-branch
```

Comment: What is `coworker_remote` mean? Also the repo belongs to me, not her

Comment: `coworker_remote` is the name I gave to your coworke's remote. I assumed you each had your own. So you are both pushing to the same remote (public repo)? Does she have her own branch? If so, merge her branch into yours. `git merge origin/coworkers_branch`

Comment: No, she does not have her own branch. She checked out my branch and added a commit to it, then pushed it back to my remote branch.

Answer (score 10):

You need to update your branch
git pull origin *your branch name*

Answer (score 7):

I think it helps to realize that branches are *specific to one particular Git repository*.  Your co-worker did not make a commit on your branch.  She made one on a different branch that may or may not have had the same *name*.

You're using *two* repositories.  One is yours, on your computer.  The second one is the one on GitHub.  These two different repositories have different branches.  These different branches may have the same *names*, and once you fetch (get commits from them) or push (send commits to them), the different branches can have the same commits too: after that, you can call them "the same", but they're still different in an important way: changing one won't affect the other (yet).

You co-worker is also (probably) using at least two repositories: hers, and one on GitHub.  You probably can't reach hers directly, but you should be able to reach the one on GitHub.  That one on GitHub may even be the same one on GitHub that you already use.

If your co-worker is using the *same repository* on GitHub that you are using on GitHub, you already have a name in your own Git for that repository.  You call it `origin`.  You can run `git fetch origin` to obtain commits from `origin`.  That other Git—the one on GitHub—has various branch names in it.  Your Git will get their commits, then *rename* their branches to `origin/whatever` in *your* repository, so that no matter what names *they* have, yours are different—yours don't start with `origin/`.  (Technically, your `origin/*` names are *remote-tracking names* rather than branch names, but the important thing here is that they start with `origin/`.)

If your co-worker is using a *different* repository on GitHub, you will need to create another *remote* in your own Git repository:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

where the *`name`* part is whatever name you want to use—I don't know your co-worker's name; I'll just use `alice` here—and the *`url`* part is the URL needed to reach that Git on GitHub:

```
git remote add alice <url>
```

Now you can run:

```
git fetch alice
```

which will bring over any commits in that repository that you don't have, and rename those branches to `alice/master`, `alice/develop`, and so on—basically, all your new "remote-tracking" `alice/*` names.

Now you will have the commit she made.  She made it in her own repository, where it was totally private, but she then sent it to her GitHub repository, where you could get it.  You got it, and now it's in *your* own repository, so now you can use it.  If Alice made it on a branch named `WIP-my-branch`, then sent it to her GitHub repository under the branch named `WIP-my-branch`, you now have it under *your* `alice/WIP-my-branch`.

Comment: Very helpful. Follow-up question, when the pull request is approved will it automatically also merge my coworkers commit or do I need to push again (after a fetch+merge)?

Comment: @nthobservation: there are a lot of possible setups here, but in general, if a PR is approved and merged, whoever is controlling whichever Git repository had the PR placed into it in the first place, has now merged (or perhaps rebased or squashed) the commit(s) in the PR into some branch in that Git repository. That is, suppose the PR repository is at https://github.com/user/repo.git. Then *that* Git now has some new commit(s) on some branch specific to that Git repository. You can `git fetch` these commits into your own local repository and put them on whatever branch(es) you like in yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge origin/coworkers_branch
```

You can find your `coworkers_branch` in Github. In your PR, under Commits, click into your coworker's commit.
Their local branch name will usually be listed under the commit message title on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch origin <your_branch_name>
```

worked with me

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following, please correct me if I am wrong

1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git checkout <my_branch>
4. git pull
5. git merge master

Answer (score -1):

git merge <your coworker's commit_hash>